# CORS angular js + restEasy on POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resteasy

I'm doing some **POST** requests from my **angular js** app to my **RESTful API** implemented using **RestEasy**.
The case is that I need **CORS** so I added a servlet filter with this code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

But I can't figure out why it works only with **GET** requests and not **POST** requests, the error on chrome's console is:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

My POST request is:

```
$http({method: 'POST', 
       url: myUrl,
       data: $scope.data,
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

This is the reponse I receive on POST:

```
Allow:POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 03 Apr 2014 23:27:22 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Any Idea? Thanks!
**EDIT:**
Tested on IE10 and it works but doesn't work on chrome neither firefox ... any body knows why?

Comment: how are you requesting with GET?

Comment: the same way but with 'GET' instead of 'POST' and another url but on the same WS

Comment: i don't think you need to explicitly allow the `Content-Type` header. try and remove that.

Comment: still doesn't work, as you see in my edit, it seems that its browser thing ... FF and chrome doesn't receive the same response headers as IE

Comment: works on IE but not on Chrome or Firefox? that's [odd](http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS).

Comment: also, try and change the `Content-Type` header on the request to `text/plain`.

Comment: one more guess: use `addHeader` instead of `setHeader`

Comment: yes, searching a little I found out that FF and chrome change the request headers and use the called "preflight requests", I can't put it on text/plain because my POST consumes directly JSON to map it

Comment: it's a hack, of course, but you can still use `text/plain` if you serialize the payload just before sending it, e.g. `angular.toJson($scope.data)`.

Comment: in order to use the @Consumes annotations you need to send the correct data type not a plain/text representing you json

Comment: uhm, *what `@Consumes` annotations*? you haven't posted any servlet code...

Comment: google it, it's part of the JEE spec

Comment: right, i'm asking (in my serpentine way), where's that code of yours? how did you use those annotations?

Comment: i don't need to post it since my problem is whith allowing preflight requests, IE creates a POST request and it works perfectly, while Chrome and FF creates an OPTIONS encapsulating the POST and I don't know how to make it work

Comment: the only way i see possible would be using another content type suitable for simple request, and consuming such type in the server, thus avoiding the trigger of preflight requests. hope i'm proved wrong, it sounds unlikely that this is the only option....

Comment: Are you sending credentials with your request? `app.config(function($httpProvider) { $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I came to this workaround:
The reason it worked with IE is because IE sends directly a **POST** instead of first a preflight request to ask for permission.
But I still don't know why the filter wasn't able to manage an **OPTIONS** request and sends by default headers that aren't described in the filter (seems like an override for that only case ... maybe a restEasy thing ...)

So I created an **OPTIONS** path in my rest service that rewrites the reponse and includes the headers in the response using response header

> I'm still looking for the clean way to do it if anybody faced this
>   before.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck configuring Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) for my API (on Wildfly) by using this lib:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
<artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It's very easy to setup. Just add the above dependency to your pom and then add the following config to the webapp section of your web.xml file.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <!-- CORS Filter mapping -->
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can also configure it with a properties file instead if you prefer. This lib works like a charm and gives you a lot of configuration flexibility!