# CORS angularjs $http.get

Tags: angularjs, cors

I'm trying to consume a josn api (I'm very new to angularjs) and I'm getting the following error when trying to consume a json api using $http.get

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

- angularjs version: 1.3.8
- browser: chrome/firefox/safari
- enable CORS on the server side is not an option
- already tried jsonp without success
- the url works when I use the browser (I see the json response)

My Code:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
})

.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

var url = "https://myurl";

$http.get(url)
.success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

});

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the headers on the server side?

Comment: @WayneEllery, he/she said that enabling CORS on the server side is not an option

Comment: @iH8 Then CORS won't work then

Comment: @Angad read the question, jsonp failed

Comment: If API isn't CORS enabled or serve jsonp you have to use a proxy

Comment: did you try $http.jsonp without overriding $httpProvider defaults?

Comment: @charlietfl Can you elaborate using proxy thing  ?

Comment: google `ajax proxy`.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23823010/2559712