# Google plus CORS error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, oauth, cors

i have implemented AngularJS application that is using https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

The problem is that my AngularJS is on one server and Rest Api is at the other server. When I tried to login everything goes ok until my callback function calls rest api.

This is the error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://liveboard-dev.locastic.com/api/v1/login. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

There is no problem with server as I can call this method from any part of code except when i am sending auth response directly from google which I got after popup window is closed.

My angularjs code for calling api is:

```
        $http.post(applicationSettings.authenticationAPIUrl, authResult['code'], {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'}}).success(function (response) {

        identityService.setIdentity(response);
        deferred.resolve(response);

    }).error(function (error) {

        deferred.reject(error);
    });
```

Comment: did you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs

Comment: yes, but i dont want to build proxy server, as my server application is already some kind of proxy

Comment: I mean did you enabled your CORS on angular js ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan how do you mean?

Comment: I've posted like answer

Answer (score 1):

Enabling CORS in Angular side

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myAppApiService']);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

Comment: CORS has to be enabled by the _receiver_ of the request, not the sender.

Comment: @CBroe it also need to be enabled in AngularJS

Comment: @Narek: That might be an Angular-specific thing, but is not the main part of CORS.

Comment: @CBroe on server is everything ok as I can send request with no problem. Only problem is when i send code recieved from popup google window

Comment: @CBroe that's why I said **it also** :)