# When trying too load a web api with AngularJS I keep getting a CORS error in my console

Tags: angularjs

**When Running my code this error pops up in the console!**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.sportsdatallc.org/mlb-t5/games/2015/04/12/boxscore.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

**This is my server.js file**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function (){
    console.log('### Server is listening on PORT: ', server.address().port);
});
```

I did some research and it showed used this line but im confused on where i put the express.static line also!

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**EDIT 1**

ok, It's much of server side thing , if u don't have control on sportsdatallc.org domain u can't modify their headers and allow cross origin requests.

However if u r writing ur own server(if u own sportsdatallc.org ) which i thought earlier as u mentioned `server.js` , then u can put this cors logic to allow cross domain requests.

u can confirm if it's a cors issue by some live test servers like http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client or https://httpbin.org/ depending on in which domain u host angular app .

Also I am not sure if it's completely correct but u can use a proxy kind of approach , you can put ur server in org domain and route all request through that , ofc in ur server u can allow cors ref http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: @ChrisManfredi from your angular code are u trying to hit localhost:3000/ or http://api.sportsdatallc.org/mlb-t5/games/2015/04/12/boxscore.json.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547003/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r

Comment: I am trying too hit api.sportsdatallc.org

Comment: @ChrisManfredi one more quick thing, https://wordnik-play-server.herokuapp.com is a cors enabled server , tested this and your url at http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client , seems like later is not enabled.  plz accept or upvote if it helps

Answer (score -1):

HELP! Still confused on this topic!