# AngularJS HTTP Header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, header

I have a some problems. AngularJS application data from external url. This is my code. How to write authorization header. Response is HTTP status 401.

```
app.controller('AddressController', function($scope, $http){
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'username password';
$http.get('http://URL/resources/cities?sortBy=cityId&sortOrder=asc&offset=0&limit=100').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.posts = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });
});
```

Comment: Which external service are you using? I mean something like Apache.

Comment: Did you got it sorted out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem in past, more precisely, a **CORS** problem.
You can read more about **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)** on:

- [Wikipedia about CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
- [Google Documentation about CORS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin)

In few words, CORS happens when you haven't set the permission to access a specific file or data on a web service, in your case, on your **Apache2** service.
So, when you try to access them, it just tells you: **"Response is HTTP status 401, Access Denied"**

In order to solve this, in other words, allowing the access to your resource, you can make two things:

- Fix your Apache2 .config file
- Setting the permission on your AngularJS Controllers

I've always went for the first option, fixing my Apache2 .config file.
You can find your **Apache2.conf** file in some of Apache2 folder.
Just check in [it's documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).

Now I'm going to show you how I fixed the problem. In few words, I had some **Jsons** on my Apache2 server and I needed them to be fetched on my **AngularJS Controllers** in order to display some data in my **Views**.

I had something like:

**myController.js**

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope","$http",function($scope, $http){

    var controller = this;

    $http.get('http://localhost/main.json').success(function(dataForViews){

        controller.data = dataForViews;

    })  
}]);
```

And in my **Html Views** I just requested the data with syntax like:

```
<p> {{myController.dataForViews.Name}} </p>
```

Now, In order to allow the access, I put this code on my **Apache2.config**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    ServerAdmin yourName@yourName

    #Giving permissions
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    ############################ Main Page ###########################
    Alias /main.json /var/www/html/myApp/data/mainPages/mainJSON.json

    #When localhost/myApp, you get the application that runs on localhost:9000 
    #with its jsons
    <Location /myApp>
        ProxyPass  http://localhost:9000/
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:9000/
    </Location>

    #Same thing for scripts, css, etc, like:
    <Location /scripts>
      ProxyPass  http://localhost:9000/scripts/
      ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:9000/scripts/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I was able to allow the access to my resources lying on my Apache2 server like this.
Now, you may solve like I did or, if you get some errors, you may need to look at [Apache2 Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/)

If you want so solve it in the AngularJS way, take a look at:

- This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs) by @Quentin
- This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547003/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r?lq=1) by @CapK
- And other related Q/A

I hope I've been helpful.