# Go into object with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have trouble with my JSON-Files. I have an old one that works fine.

Now i get a new and i didn't find the way into the first "main_themes"-Object.

This is my actual module:

```
     angular.module('destinationsApp', [])
  .controller('destinationsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MAHUKI-Webdesign/suntrips.github.io/master/data.json').then(function(itemsResponse) {
      $scope.items = itemsResponse.data;
    });
});
```

Actually i make it with something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></li>
```

How i have to do it?

Here's my Plunkr with the working version:

https://embed.plnkr.co/U4WHAFQRZ2JsUOJVlAu7/

Here's my Plunkr with the not working version:

https://embed.plnkr.co/b3OtRKgzp1OQ0h1L3jDA/

Comment: Open your browser's debugger; do you see any errors?

Comment: Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://www2.suntrips.de/import/main_sub_themes-main.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}

Comment: This part is simply because there is an error handler missing (i.e. you did not use .catch()); that's not the cause of your problem; rather, Plunker's HTTPS protocol is.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/MAHUKI-Webdesign/suntrips.github.io/master/data.json";
$http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: url
}).
success(function(status) {
     $scope.items = itemsResponse.data;
                // handle valid reponse
}).
error(function(status) {
    //your code when fails
});
```

You are getting  `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin` to solve this change the rest api to give access to the localhost.Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547003/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r) .. Use JSONP

Comment: Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: wd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }

Comment: Thanks but i'm more designer than developer so  i failed once more

Comment: use this $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: url
}) instead of http.get

Comment: You mean like this:


angular.module('destinationsApp', [])
  .controller('destinationsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http({ method: 'JSONP', url:'http://www2.suntrips.de/import/main_sub_themes-main.json'}).then(function(itemsResponse) {
      $scope.items = itemsResponse.data.main_themes;
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

since the response is an object just access the `main_themes` property.

```
 $scope.items = itemsResponse.data.main_themes
```

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: there is a problem with the cors. you need to put access allow headers in the server side

Answer (score 0):

Access the **`main_themes`**

```
 $scope.items = itemsResponse.data.main_themes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Plunkr with the **working** version:

https://embed.plnkr.co/U4WHAFQRZ2JsUOJVlAu7/

Here's my Plunkr with the **not working** version:

https://embed.plnkr.co/b3OtRKgzp1OQ0h1L3jDA/

Answer (score 0):

It does not work on Plunker;

Error that I got:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/b3OtRKgzp1OQ0h1L3jDA?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www2.suntrips.de/import/main_sub_themes-main.json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

Please make requests to server using HTTPS protocol when using Plunker.