# Cross-origin Ajax request to API returns 500 (Internal Server Error) response

Tags: angularjs, http, http-status-code-500

I am getting error response '500 (Internal Server Error)' when I do a `GET` call to an api. Here’s the error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.4.217' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

…though I get a response when I try from postman or using the curl command.

In this call, I have to pass an id in header. Here is the code:

```
this.getState = function () {
        return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus',
                headers: {'Jab_Device_id': '80f1374192a6d6eb9ebf48e2eba18366','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                });
    };
```

Also, I tried with Ajax but with that I also got the same error. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus',
        headers: {
          'Jab_Device_id':'80f1374192a6d6eb9ebf48e2eba18366'  
        },
        method: 'GET',
        withCredentials: true,
        success: function(data){
          console.log('succes: '+data);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Does services have CORS implemented?, what are the allowed calling sources.

Comment: yes. It has. Otherwise i wouldn't have got response through postman or using curl command.

Comment: The fact that you get a response from postman or using the curl command doesn’t tell you that CORS support is configured on the `http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus` server. Even if CORS isn’t configured there, you’ll still be able to get a response using postman or the curl command

Comment: Because your request adds a `Jab_Device_id` header, that triggers your browser to do a [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). So to emulate what’s happening here using curl, you need to do this: `curl -X OPTIONS -i -H 'Origin: http://192.168.4.217/' 
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' 
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Jab_Device_id' 
    http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus`. If you try that with curl, I bet you’ll get back the same 500 response your browser gets.

Comment: I used this:-
curl --verbose -X GET -H "Jab_Device_Id":"2df37485bd7d2835b16ba40649cd0c2f" -H "Accept: application/json" http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus

and i got the response

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://10.10.14.188:4800/api/v1/healthMonitor/DeviceStatus";
$http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Jab_Device_id': '80f1374192a6d6eb9ebf48e2eba18366','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).
success(function(status) {
    //your code when success
}).
error(function(status) {
    //your code when fails
});
```

CORS is Cross Origin Resource Sharing, you get this error if you are trying to access from one domain to another domain.

Try using JSONP. In your case, JSONP should work fine because it only uses the GET method.

Try something like this:

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547003/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r)

But if you have access to the rest api update filters to enable CORS request if you cant to perform all other operation

Comment: how would i add header in this?

Comment: Just to note, if there is an internal server error, then the CORS error message in the browser can be a red herring. It could just be a server error that is causing the issue, and the request is correct.

Comment: Cors and server error are separate unless server error is in the CORS ..  if he gets valid error then  there might be problem with the servers ..

Answer (score 0):

This was not to do with api server. This application is running on ngnix server and cors needs to be enabled from client side also. I just added this code in default file and it worked.

```
location / {
         if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
         }
    }
```

Comment: what is $request_method