# Failed to load http://localhost:5000/api/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

My problem is that I am trying to login to asp.net core backend with angular2.

The response contains token and is `200 OK`, but always the error called with `status 0 unknown error` and this error appears:

> Failed to load http://localhost:5000/api/token: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

so any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547003/angularjs-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r)

Comment: it is not angularjs. Although it is a server side problem indeed.

Comment: FrestG so what is the solution?

Comment: @Montaser In production environment your apps (Angular & Asp.Net Core app) will run under the same domain or different domain? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS problem. You need to allow CORS so you can call your api service from different domain. Currently you are trying to call http://localhost:5000 from http://localhost:4200 which is not allowed since theese are different domains. In your API service aplication go to Startup.cs file and in your ConfigureServices method you must configure CORS. Try something like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
      services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowCredentials();
        }));
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i am facing same issue, please can u specify more where the API service application and the Startup.cs file? i can't find them, Thanks, i am using php as serve side language

Comment: Hi Aly! This answer was intended for people that use asp.net for backend. Since you are using PHP as your backend technology there is no Startup.cs class in your project. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers