# java API and angular SPA in the same Azure App Service

Tags: angularjs, spring, api, azure-web-app-service

can i run, in one single app service, my java API as a virtual application under /api and my frontend angular SPA on under / ?

in my application settings:

- i've set Java to version 8
- i've set the web container to Tomcat 9
- in the virtual application section i have:

  - virtual directory: / and path: site\wwwroot
  - virtual directory: /api and path: site\wwwroot\api
  - both are marked as Application

After i deploy both virtual apps, when i go to the app service URL, i get the frontend correctly, but there is also a call to the API which stays in pending for a couple of minutes  and then ends in a 500 error.
If i try to access the API directly, i get the same 500 error.

The API was built with Spring and it's web.config file i have set:

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
            <add initializationPage="/api"/>
            <add initializationPage="/api/health"/>
            <add initializationPage="/api/info"/>
        </applicationInitialization>
```

I want both, API and SPA, to be on the same domain. Currently, API is accessible from any domain, no restrictions on it.

What am i doing wrong? How can i make it work?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it's not necessary to create `virtual directory` when you deploy your web project to Azure App Service.

After you set `application settings` on portal,

[image]

You could put your project's generated `war package` under the `D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps` directory on `KUDU` and restart your application.

[image]

Please note that if you set the name of the war package to `ROOT.war`, you will be able to access your application directly through the `domain name`,such as `http://jaygong.azurewebsites.net/` without adding your war package name in your request url.

You could also access static files directly through the path,such as `http://jaygong.azurewebsites.net/image/image.jpg`.

---

***Updated answer***

Per my experience,you could use two ways to call another app service API in your spring boot app service.

1.The front page of the spring boot calls the background method, transfer messages between another app service API and itself via the `HTTP` request, and returns the result to the front end. `CORS` issue does not exist in this way.

2.The front page of the spring boot calls another app service API directly.
You could refer to the js below which in this thread [Enable CORS AngularJS to send HTTP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915657/enable-cors-angularjs-to-send-http-post-request)

```
allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: the thing is that i am using spring boot for the backend which is a JAR not a WAR file. so i have a web.config for it to be able to start it with java. also i already have an app service for the API, and it's working, but i want the API on the same app service as the frontend, so i can serve them from the same domain (i want to implement CSRF/XSRF and CORS). this way, the API can be accesed from frontend with only relative paths.