# Calling WCF REST service using AngularJs giving error

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, wcf

I am  trying to call my **WCF REST** service(hosted in non PROD environment) from my local machine using **AngularJS**. But everytime i am getting

**SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://XXX/XXX/Web/rest/GeDetails required CORS preflight.**

and

**SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.**

Is there any way i can consume WCF REST service using AngularJS ?

thanks!

Comment: It seems that you have CORS issues, you cannot call a web server from a site hosted in other server. Maybe, if you show us the request and answer we can help you to know which information is missing in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used below code in my service global.asax page and its working perfect.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a CORS error.

You must enable CORS in your api -> [enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

for WCF Rest try [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html)

And then in your angular.config you must:

```
    angular.module('myapp',[...])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        // ...
  })
```

Apparently in the latest AngularJS versions you don't have to add anything to make it [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs). But actually for me works in this way.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, But i am facing issue with accessing WCF REST service, not with web api.