# `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postman

So, when I looked up the error, I see mostly it has something to do with with the webservice.
The problem is that I cant touch the webservice. However, using Postman extension on chrome it returns data just fine. So, i tend to believe that there is something wrong on frontend.

Also, Im using angular and rather at beginner's level, so I might be missing something trivial.

```
.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http){ 

    return $http.get('https://link') 
        .success(function(data) { 
            return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
            return err; 
        }); 
   }
]);
```

Comment: From code in an ordinary page, you cannot issue HTTP requests via ajax to servers that don't explicitly indicate that they allow it by returning that header. Browser extensions are a different story - they can do anything.

Comment: [same origin policy, again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource, will help you

Answer (score 3):

You will always get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error if the webservice you are trying to access via REST doesn't have that header set for the response you are aiming to get.

However, most of the times, you can get around it by making a `Server -> Server` request instead of a `Client -> Server (AJAX)` request.

For example, if you are using NodeJS as a backend and make the request from there, then send the response back to your client via Node, you should be fine.

**EDIT:** Also, as stated in the comments (forgot that, thanks), AngularJS's `$http` service also exposes a `$http.jsonp` method using which you can get around that. However that only works if the webservice you are trying to access also exposes the information as `JSONP` in their API.

[Documentation on $http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: or if api serves jsonp... if you are going to answer a question it should at least provide all options

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that, but its added now :)