# angular POST request not working but GET working fine

Tags: angularjs, laravel, http-headers, cors, content-type

I know this has been asked, but I tried a lot of things and could not make this work.

I am making GET and POST request from my angular application to laravel backend api's. I am able to fetch json from get request but my POST request fails for json data type. It works for

```
x-www-form-urlencoded
```

but I am unable to extract data as it is in json format.

```
$http.get('http://api.app.mywebsite.com/users').success(function(data){
    $scope.user = data;
});

$scope.addUser = function(user){
    console.log($scope.user);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api.app.mywebsite.com/users',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $scope.user,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
}

$scope.user is posted on form submit.
```

The error I get :-

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.app.mywebsite.com/users. 
Response     to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-    Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested   resource. Origin 'http://app.mybackend.com' is therefore not     allowed access.
```

My CORS.php middleware in laravel :-

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return \Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
    return $next($request);
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Are you receiving an error? Please be more clear about what you are expecting and what is actually happening.

Comment: I get the following error message "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Have update my question.

Comment: what headers WERE sent with the preflight according to the browser?

Comment: Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.app.mywebsite.com
Origin:http://app.mybackend.com
Referer:http://app.mybackend.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

Update:
http://let-aurn.github.io/laravel-5-cors/

You need to configure your http server to allow cors 
Similar question:
[How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)

And:
[AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Comment: well my server is working for GET request, which means CORS is working, so I am assuming there's some problem at client side..

Comment: Check the added SO question as well.