# Angular $http.get call to web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http, cors, http-get

I have two web applications running.  App1 is an angular SPA and App2 is an MVC web api written in c#. I am executing both applications from Visual Studio 2015, running debug in IIS Express.

My angular code (App1) is trying to call an api controller in App2 using the following (debug) code:

```
$http.get('https://localhost:12345/api/values').then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
        }, function (err) { 
            alert(err);
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log("error", e);
            throw e;
        }) .finally(function () {
            console.log("This finally block");
        });
```

I always hit the "alert(err);" line - it never successfully executes and err has nothing useful in it to indicate what the problem could be.

In Postman (addin for Chrome), I can confirm the call I'm trying to make to App2 works fine.  What am I doing wrong?  Could this be an issue with CORS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SAME ORIGIN POLICY ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Despite `err` not having anything useful in it, perhaps post the content anyway.  Also, since you've got both sites running in the debugger, does the controller action actually get hit at all?

Comment: the scheme is `HTTPS`. are you sure there is no authentication issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem I had was in the web api (MVC 6 - ASP.net 5) in that I had to allow the requests from my angular web site.  The startup.cs file had the following added:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors();

            StartupInitialize(services);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:12345/"));

            app.UseMvc();

            antiForgery = (IAntiforgery)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IAntiforgery));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either experiencing CORS/SAME ORIGIN POLICY issue that some information about it in angular js can be found here: [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs).
this is how you handle it in server site in your case: http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/security/cors-policy.html#cors-policy

or you better open the developer tools in console tab and bring us some more information about what happened in your code.