# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in angularjs for my application

Tags: angularjs

Hi i have deployed my application in filezilla and now i am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

In my browser if i disable web security it is working, without this what is the solution for this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23826620/4759033

Comment: Stop making cross-origin requests and error will disappear... Please make sure to provide [MCVE] inline in the question so it will be up to SO standards and can be answered insted of potentially being donwvoted/closed (unless you simply trying to promote your site as hidden spam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this on server side in response object.
and at the client side use **mozilla firefox browser** if your are not pushing pages through **server**.

```
function(req, res, next) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');

            if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
                res.send(200);
            }
            else {
                next();
            }
        };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: put in inside .htaccess file