# How to debug $http method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am running an angularjs app and I am having trouble finding out why my `$http` call is failing.

I type the url into the browser I always get a response.
But when I make there url request through `$http` it fails.

My code is:

```js
.controller('StopDetailCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.info = fetch();

  function fetch(){
        //This url works
        // var uriBuilder = 'http://cors-test.appspot.com/test'
        //This url doesn't
        var uriBuilder = 'http://api.translink.ca/rttiapi/v1/stops/55612?apikey=u8RWYB3HmxjsHenpDk0u'

    $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: uriBuilder
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          console.log('Success', JSON.stringify(response));
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log('Error', JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }
})
```

The error I keep getting back is a json string which is not informative.

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": 0,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "http:\/\/api.translink.ca\/rttiapi\/v1\/stops\/55612?apikey=u8RWYB3HmxjsHenpDk0u",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application\/json, text\/plain, *\/*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

Is there something I am missing in the $http request?

The api I am using is: https://developer.translink.ca/ServicesRtti/ApiReference

Comment: Inspect the actual request itself in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: Uploading image of browser dev tools.. They don't tell me anything. just saying `an error occurred trying to load the resource`

Comment: arg... I got dev error now `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.translink.ca/rttiapi/v1/stops/55612?apikey=u8RWYB3HmxjsHenpDk0u. Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: That's  CORS error. API is not CORS enabled. See if it serves jsonp or use a proxy

Comment: The url you specified in example returns xml instead of json..

Comment: @charlietfl jsonp works. but how do I specify `accept: application/JSON` in the header an xml is being returned.

Comment: unless api serves jsonp (JSON w/padding) it doesn't do you any good. If it does, you need to use `$http.jsonp` and included callback string...see docs

Comment: The call back string does not work. I put `headers: {'Accept': 'application/JSON'}` but the request header that is sent is `accept: */*`

Comment: You can't send headers with jsonp...it is actually a script request. Use a proxy on your server or third party proxy service like Yahoo YQL

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the only way to do the request is using a proxy as the only way to get a json response is by putting in the header `{'Accept': 'application/JSON'}`

Comment: See [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23824093/5535245).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make  CORS request. Adding CORS support to your application requires coordination between both the source server and client. You can create CORS request as described in this [post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). I tested it.

As I said you need to change server respose as well. So **you need support from translink and translink' server API response must include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If this header is not present in response, the CORS request will fail**.

I gone through [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/translink-developers/KF9MOHxit5c/yTt1mjWFCQAJ) TransLink Developer's topic where they have clearly mentioned that,

> "For security reasons, changing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
>   will expose the API key.  For this reason we will not be making any
>   changes at this point."

So probably CORS request to the TransLink in not feasible unless they add the API support.