# How to send json data to web api from $http service in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

While making a Ajax Request with Json object to "**Web Api**" using Angular js $http service.It raise CORS Issue,There is no Resolution by adding the following header "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" also,Please suggest me the right solution

Example:

```
var testmodule = angular.module('testmod', []);

 testmodule.controller('testcontroller', function ($scope, $http) 

{

$scope.Member ={'name':'andrew','age':12,'class':10}

$scope.savedata =function(){

$http({      
            url: "**api url**",
            method: 'POST',
            data: $scope.Member
        }).success(function (data, status) { }).error(function (data, status, headers) { })
}
})
```

Comment: Please put some code here...

Answer (score 0):

The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is a server side issue, you don't need to add any header in angularjs. add the following code to your server side:

```
("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");   
("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");         
("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");
```

you can refer to [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)

Comment: you also can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS