# Where should I write cors filter enabler code in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, cors

This is my js file, the following code is inside .controller

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200){
    $http.post(smsHorizon,'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').then(function(res){
      res.addheader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.addheader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
      res.addheader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
      if(res){
        alert("OTP has been Send");
      }
    })
  }
  else{

  }
}
```

Is this the way to code cors? Please help!!!

Comment: you should add the headers in server side

Comment: this is serverside code it is using another api

Comment: A guide to enable CORS - https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

`CORS` request enabling always-on server side. You need to set `CORS` on response header.

**CORS- How Internally Work**

A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a domain or port which is different from the one which the first resource itself serves. For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.

For example:
your app running on `www.my-domain.com` and its request for the resource on `www.your-domain.com` than browser do not allow to make the request within a script.

**CORS- How To Resolve**

suppose we made a request through angular script under domain `www.my-domain.com` is `www.your-domain.com\id`. This request hit on the server at endpoint `/id` on `www.your-domain.com`. So, at a time of rendering/sending a response by the server, it set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` header in the response.

```
//java-jersey example
Response.status(200).entity(data)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
                    .build();
```

---

```
//Nodejs Example
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
```

For more details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS