# controller is hitting the server but data is not displaying in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, controller

When I click on a button it will go to controller and hit the server through **API** and return the data into the html page.  
I have created my own API and placed in Cloud I am accessing it through web address, I am not using any other sites api. The code which I written is hitting the server through API but the data is not displaying.

**My HTML Code**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="testctrl">
        <button ng-click="loadtestctrl()">Load ctrl</button>
        {{result}}

    </div>
```

**My Controller Code**

```
app.controller("testctrl",function($scope,$http){
            $scope.loadtestctrl = function(){
                $http.get("http://192.168.0.103:8081/kunera-pos/franchise/getFranchise/").then(function(response){
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                });
            }

        });
```

The three Error which I am getting are  
**Error 1**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**Error 2**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.103:8081/kunera-pos/franchise/getFranchise/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

**Error 3**

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://192.168.0.103:8081/kunera-pos/franchise/getFranchise/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}

I cant find out where I am making mistake.  
**I am using Angularjs CDN 1.6.5**  
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible dupe of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)