# Cross-Origin Request Blocked when sending post

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing application in Angular 5.

When I try to send request:

```
this.httpClient.post("https://api.textlocal.in/send/", new Message(this.apiKey, "xxxxxxxxx", "TEST", "SOIS_App")
```

I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.textlocal.in/send/. (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-headers’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

How can I get CORB when I am sending request form my computer to https://api.textlocal.in ??

Comment: CORS headers are added on your server, need to do it there.

Comment: As i mentioned: This is not my server. I am using someones API

Comment: As I mentioned: CORS headers are added on your server.  Whoever controls it needs to allow your host.  This is basic web security.

Comment: Is it possible that https://www.textlocal.com api does not support that?

Comment: Alternatively, you can submit your request from the server (your server) side.

Comment: You need to contact textlocal.com, you cant just use random API's in your applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get CORB when I am sending request form my computer to https://api.textlocal.in

Enable CORS on your your server for address `localhost` (or wherever you are running the app from).

## Detailed guide

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

## Quick guide

1. Enable an `OPTIONS` endpoint
2. Enable headers on your post:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`