# HTTP Get request from angular to spring backend being blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring, angular, rest, xmlhttprequest

I have a @RestController in my java spring backend:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getItems")
public List<Item> getItems()
{
    System.out.println("Requested!");
    return itemRepository.findAll();
}
```

I am trying to retreive the items in my Angular frontend but get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/getItems' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control- 
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But I am not sure why, because I am adding the correct header in Angular:

```
getItems() {
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getItems',
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    }
  )})
  .subscribe(
  data => {console.log(data);
  });
}
```

The get request does work in Postman, but I know that the browser is what is causing the problem, and requires that the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to be present, which I added.
It compiles, but it seems like it's not adding the headers correctly. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Oh it seems like I can add a @CrossOrigins annotation in my RestController and specify an origin in the backend!