# How to get data from JSONP APIs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ip, jsonp

### How to get Client IP address in Angular JS using external APIs? I always get response as "" ? The browser I am using is BRAVE

I need to get client API from Angular frontend and send it back to Backend(SPRINGBOOT). I tried many external APIs but I am getting "" as response data. How to get response in AngularJS?
I am using the below code to get API response.

I tried http://jsonip.com?callback=? . It works well in browser and postman, but while I try console.log(response.data) the output is ""

```
$http.get("randomeOnlineAPI").then(handleSuccess, handleRemoteError);
```

I need to get API response and then send back the received ip to backend.

Answer (score 0):

For JSONP APIs, use:<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58330746/5535245)</sup>

```
 var url = "//api.ipify.org/";
 var trust = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
 $http.jsonp(trust,{params: {format:'jsonp'}})
   .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
     $scope.response = response.data;
 }).catch(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
     $scope.response = 'ERROR: ' + response.status;
 })
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6NPy9DIfFPvnUwhIyMs?p=preview)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - $http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: I found another workaround, I tried hitting the api using this https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/API-YOU-WANT

eg: I used $http.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.ipify.org/?format=text');

Comment: I tried jsonp , but still it is blocked by Cross Orgin Read Blocking with MIME type application/json.

Comment: The example in the question showed an API that supports JSONP. If the API doesn't support JSONP and it doesn't allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, then the only choice is to access it from your own server or a proxy. Browsers block cross-origin requests from JavaScript to protect users from evil JavaScript.