# gocd - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, api, oauth, cors, go-cd

I want to upload artifacts to a gocd pipeline using their API which is `POST /go/files/:pipeline_name/:pipeline_counter/:stage_name/:stage_counter/:job_name/*path_to_file`. I have nodejs application with google oauth2 enabled. I am uploading files and uploading them using POST request in angularjs.

```
<script>
    angular.module('fupApp', [])
        .directive('ngFiles', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

            function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
                var onChange = $parse(attrs.ngFiles);
                element.on('change', function (event) {
                    onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
                });
            };

            return {
                link: fn_link
            }
        } ])
        .controller('fupController', function ($scope, $http) {

            var formdata = new FormData();
            $scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
                angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
                    formdata.append(key, value);
                });
            };

            // NOW UPLOAD THE FILES.
            $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

                var request = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://<mydomain1.net>:8154/go/files/FirstPipeline/13/defaultStage/1/defaultJob/',
                    data: formdata,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                  };

                // SEND THE FILES.
                $http(request)
                    .success(function (d) {
                        alert(d);
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                    });
            }
        });
</script>
```

I am trying to request from **mydomain2.net** to **mydomain1.net**(this is gocd). However in browser after selecting a file and clicking on submit, I get this error after I inspect(Ctrl+Shift+I).

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mydomain1:8154/go/files/FirstPipeline/13/defaultStage/1/defaultJob/' from origin 'http://mydomain2:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Where should the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header be added at GoCD side?

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking at the GoCD sources and docs, it has no built-in support for CORS. It seems that instead the recommended way to enable making requests to it from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser is to put a “reverse proxy” in between (similar to what @talhature suggests). See the docs at https://docs.gocd.org/current/installation/configure-reverse-proxy.html

Comment: @sideshowbarker, Thank you. I will be considering reverse proxy. Can you help me with where do I need to add the configuration if I want to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header at gocd server side? Is it after installing nginx where my server is at and then in some file or where? I am completely new to nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cross-origin error is raised by browsers when one web page that's under a different domain tries to access the resources of a different domain.

If the requester is not a browser, CORS is not applicable.
So you can set up a proxy server in between. Check this question's edit section: [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23823010/11420760)

Normally, proxies shouldn't be used in real applications in production, but as far as I understand, what you are trying to achieve is CI/CD integration for your development workflow. So it should be fine.

You can also google how you can set a proxy for AngularJS in NodeJS environment.

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer!  I'll try out reverse proxy : )

Comment: Your wellcome, I hope you do not miss the fact that what I reffered as proxy is a reverse proxy here. So don't you think I deserve at least an upvote :)